# Can I change a docker container from a self-delete policy to auto-restart?

Tags: docker

I've got a container started (not my code, not my container, but I often manage the server and deal with the aftermath of it being patched) and I need to make a hot-fix to the deployment strategy, I had gone through the steps to change it to auto-restart, but a coworker noticed that the container was started with `--rm`.  My guess is that this is circumventing any attempt to start it up after reboots (because the container just isn't there any more)

So is there a way to remove the `--rm` policy from a running container?

Comment: the real answer here is - convince the docker owner to enable swarm mode and deploy as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a docker update.
(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/).

`docker update --restart always <containerID>/<containerName>`.

Not sure about removing the --rm flag, though

Comment: Welcome to the site Bryan, I'm sorry but this doesn't quite answer my question.   I know how to set the autostart parameters, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't help since the container is set to auto remove.